# Lwt_stream usage and design concern

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a lwt-based Twitter API library and I want to implement the Twitter API's [cursor](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/cursoring) functionality using Lwt_stream library.

I decide to use `Lwt_stream.from` and supply this function an argument `f`.

Here is what I currently do

```
let get_follower ~access_token ~screen_name ?(count=5000) ?(wait=true) () =
  let base_uri = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json" in
  let cursor = ref (-1) in
  let f () =
    Client.do_get_request
      ~uri_parameters:
        ["screen_name", screen_name;
         "cursor", (string_of_int (!cursor));
         "count", (string_of_int count)]
      ~uri:(Uri.of_string base_uri)
      ~access_token:access_token
    () >>= fun res ->
    match res with
    | Ok (header, str) -> begin
      match (Yojson.Safe.from_string str |> user_ids_of_yojson) with
      | `Ok uids -> 
        cursor := uids.next_cursor;
        return (Some (Ok uids))
      | `Error msg -> failwith msg 
      end
    | Error e -> return (Some (Error (process_error_exn e))) in
  Lwt_stream.from f
```

I am not sure if I should use `ref`. **The reason I use `ref` is that the behavior of `f` depends on the value it returns previously.** To be specific, the value of `cursor` which will be used next time depends on current `next_cursor`, and if `cursor` is zero, `f` knows it reaches the end and returns `None`.

Is using `ref` here considered a good design choice? Is there any better way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Antron gave an excellent answer to my opinion, but I would like just to share with few practical advice. If I were you, I wouldn't use one big function named `f` with a `ref`, well, mostly because it smells, and it is quite unreadable and doesn't scale. I would create a stream using `Lwt_stream.create` and work with it using a recursive function, that do the main loop, with all the logic separated in helper functions. The main loop function can have state with which it recurs, so that we don't need ugly references or explicit mutability.

So, below is an example, of how your code can be restructured. I also didn't find an explicit check for a zero cursor, that should be used to stop the stream (as you mentioned in text), so I added this. Otherwise the code should work as yours.

So, I've split it into three functions: `make_request` is responsible for making the request. `parse_response` is a pure transformation, that deconstructs the answer. And finally, `loop` function performs the main loop, makes requests, parses them and stops on zero.

Note: looks like that you're using `Or_error` monad and mixing it with exceptions. This is a bad idea, since it breaks precondition, that a well formed function that returns `Or_error.t` should never throw exception.

```
let get_follower ~access_token ~screen_name ?(count=5000) ?(wait=true) () =
  let base_uri = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json" in
  let make_request cursor = 
    Client.do_get_request
      ~uri:(Uri.of_string base_uri) ~access_token    
      ~uri_parameters:[
        "screen_name", screen_name;
        "cursor", string_of_int cursor;
        "count", string_of_int count
      ] () in 
  let parse_response = function
    | Error e -> Error (process_error_exn e)
    | Ok (header, str) -> 
      match Yojson.Safe.from_string str |> user_ids_of_yojson with
      | `Ok uids -> Ok uids
      | `Error msg -> failwith msg in
  let stream,push = Lwt_stream.create () in
  let rec loop cursor = 
    make_request cursor >|= parse_response >>= function
    | Ok {next_cursor=0} -> push None; return_unit
    | Ok {next_cursor=n} as r -> push (Some r); loop n
    | error -> push (Some error); loop cursor in
  async (fun () -> loop (-1));
  stream
```

### Update

But of course this implementation will eagerly pull data from the server, and push it downstream. It is like a pump and pipe system. As soon as function is invoked, the pump it turned on and it will constantly pour water into the system. You can put a tap, by using bounded push, that can be obtained with `Lwt_stream.create_bounded`. But you will still have some amount of prefetching (or back to our pipe system analogy, you will have some kind of extension tank). Usually, this is not bad, as it removes some latency, but sometimes this is not what you want. In this case the only choice, that is left is to use explicit reference cell, to control your loop (and build stream using `Lwt_stream.from`). Other approach would be to change the interface, maybe you're trying to pack to much stuff into one abstraction. Maybe returning `follower list Lwt.t` or even `follower Lwt.t list` would be better. Or you can even create an abstract type `follower` that would hide a thread and return `follower list`, and lift it's accessors into the `_ Lwt.t`, e.g.,

```
 module Follower : sig
   type t
   val name : t -> string Lwt.t
   ...
 end
```

In that case, this interface can be quite usable with `Lwt_list` module.

Comment: Is it right that this has slightly different semantics compared to using `Lwt_stream.from`, in that it potentially submits requests and buffers the results before they are requested by each call to `next` on the resulting stream?

Comment: This solution is exactly what I want.

Comment: wait. is this stream actually lazy? i did some test and it seems not.

Comment: well, lazy is not a good term here, but indeed, it is eager. I've answered you and @antron in the update.

Comment: Thanks @ivg. Basically, `Lwt_stream.from` creates "lazy" streams (action taken only upon consumer's call to `next`) and `Lwt_stream.create` creates "eager" streams (asynchronously prefetch as much as possible and buffer, return available results on call to `next`). As @ivg mentioned, you may prefer one or the other in different situations. The "lazy" stream may end up serializing requests and processing (because of the fetch-process cycle), and so be slower, unless you take special measures to thread the consumer, but it is more "predictable" in terms of how much is retrieved and when.

Comment: ...and since I ran out of comment space: the "eager" stream saves you from having to thread the consumer if you want to escape the serialization due to the fetch-process cycle I mentioned above. The extra thread you would have to create is built into @ivg's stream creation function instead. This makes the consumer simpler and the operation can complete faster. The thread captures the state information that was captured by the ref cell in the `Lwt_stream.from` version.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that the push ("eager") stream's thread needs to be explicitly canceled if you want to abort the operation, perhaps if your consumer finishes its computation without consuming all the data. For the "lazy" stream, the consumer can simply stop calling `next`. So, in case you need to support abort, the "eager" stream creator needs to evaluate to a pair of stream and push thread, or some other handle to the push thread.

Comment: thx. I'll figure out a lazy implementation because the number of API calls you can make during a window is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Since `f` takes `unit` and produces different results each time, as you've said, it will have to depend on some state, as I think you realize. It already does that by depending on the results of I/O, and I think this is what is making the question of the `ref` non-trivial to answer. Otherwise, the answer would be yes, it is necessary (see point (2) below).

I think there are two main possibilities for eliminating the syntactic `ref`, but neither of them makes sense.

1. Hide these state bits somehow inside the I/O `f` is already doing, i.e. on the peer across the API. This doesn't seem possible, in fact it looks like the bits have to be on the client for the API to work at all.
2. Hide these state bits somewhere else on the client. But there will still be something spiritually equivalent to a `ref` somewhere in the client, in one way or another. You could write or use some kind of wrapper that factors out this `ref`, but unless that wrapper is useful in many places, it would only risk making it less obvious that there is extra client-side state here. I would prefer to keep the state as local and as close to its usage as possible. Since `f` already necessarily does "dirty" things, `f` is the right place.

So, in summary, I would say keep the `ref` as it is. It is common for streams to be stateful anyway.

---

The above discussion assumes that you have to use `Lwt_stream`. If not, you can provide an alternative interface whose type looks something like `get_follower : cursor:int -> ... -> (results * cursor) Lwt.t` and let the caller worry about state if it has to. This would probably be what I'd try first.

EDIT

There is of course a disadvantage to that, which is the possibility of writing the calling code to supply the wrong cursor. You could hide the cursor by returning a partially applied function, but the calling code might be written to call the wrong function. Without linear types, the stream approach is safer if you are worried about these possibilities, so it has its advantages.